# Blade template tags not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello I am using laravel 4.1. I am new at this framework and want to learn it. I am trying to make a simple echo like below
 `index.blade.php` (at view>customers)

```
<html>
<body>
{{ "Hello" }}
</body>
</html>
```

CustomersController.php

```
public function index(){
return View::make('customers.index');
}
```

Browser displays:
{{ "Hello" }}

What may be the problem?

Comment: is your php correctly installed?

Comment: with <?php ?> tags it works . How to check if is not ok?

Comment: what may be the problem with blade tags?

Answer (score 0):

Did you extend your customer page? also try removing {{ 'Hello' }}.

```
@extends('layout.master')

@section('content')
<!-- content here -->
@stop
```

Take a look at their docs its really helpful:
[Laravel Blade Template](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#extending-blade)

Comment: What contain layout.master? I have only index.blade.php at view. I tried your code and the same. It seems to me like doesn't recoginizes blade tags

Comment: Well in master layout, it would just simple html but with @yield('content'). Then you'd need to extend the layout like my code above.
Refer to this http://laravel.com/docs/templates#extending-blade